# HTML Style Tag in Android

Tags: html, android, android-widget, android-webview

As I have referred some articles and sites, I found that we can also create HTML file and then we can display HTML file using Android WebView..

I have referred at:

1. [Android WebView (WebKit) Tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=369)
2. [Understanding User Interface in Android - Part 4: Even More Views](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-4-even-more-views)

So my question is that:

> Is Android provides STYLE/CSS tag to define styles, if yes then there is any way to write STYLE/CSS tag in Android?

Thanx - Paresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. The Android Web View is a full fledged browser, and supports everything the built in "Browser" application supports (CSS, JavaScript). Newer versions of Android (2.2) have the V8 runtime and do great on the Acid tests.

You would use CSS as you do in any other web page.

Comment: But i am using Android 1.5 for my current application...
i will sure try it inside Android 2.2 (Froyo)..
but in Android 1.5, what i have to do for that ??

@theatrus..btw thanx for then answer

Comment: @Paresh: Nothing. CSS was supported from the beginning of (Android) time. Make a web page - it will display correctly.

Comment: @theatrus...ok i try it and let you know..
thanx for the support

Comment: @theatrus...ya every HTML pages are loading successfully..first i stored HTML with style/css in Assets Folder and then by using Webview i have loaded it.
Thanx